# Animation charts with Plotly in Jupyter: stop chart from playing until play is hit

Tags: jupyter-notebook, plotly, data-visualization

So I tried the example from Plotly

```
figure = {'data': [{'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]}],
      'layout': {'xaxis': {'range': [0, 5], 'autorange': False},
                 'yaxis': {'range': [0, 5], 'autorange': False},
                 'title': 'Start Title',
                 'updatemenus': [{'type': 'buttons',
                                  'buttons': [{'label': 'Play',
                                               'method': 'animate',
                                               'args': [None]}]}]
                },
      'frames': [{'data': [{'x': [1, 2], 'y': [1, 2]}]},
                 {'data': [{'x': [1, 4], 'y': [1, 4]}]},
                 {'data': [{'x': [3, 4], 'y': [3, 4]}],
                  'layout': {'title': 'End Title'}}]}

iplot(figure)
```

in a Jupyter notebook cell. Whenever I run the Jupyter notebook cell, the animation plays automatically. What I want is really simple, but I couldn't find a way to do it: I don't want it to start playing until I hit the play button. Is there a way to do it in the offline mode?

Comment: Did you find a solution to that problem? I am having the same issue.